# How can implement i18n Internalization in BEEGO Without Using Cookies?

Tags: go, internationalization, beego

I have added two .ini files in conf/locale_en-US.ini and conf/locale_fr-FR.ini

What should be my approach ? Where should I write my logic ? As I am a new comer in Beego Framework.

I have tried to follow this documentation:
https://github.com/beego/beedoc/blob/master/en-US/module/i18n.md

But I am understanding what to do.